# ruby on railsの起動でpumaのエラー

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx

ubuntu上でruby on railsのサーバーを立ち上げようとしています。
nginxは起動するのですが、railsがうまく接続できていません。
エラーメッセージを見ると、どうやらpumaのエラーのようです。

```
[49359c84-f723-4896-b209-988a6e3fbbaf] puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
I, [2018-10-31T09:31:39.137488 #20962]  INFO -- : [db62fb02-e52e-497f-ae19-4f7eef0db44d] Started GET "/favicon.ico" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-10-31 09:31:39 +0900
F, [2018-10-31T09:31:39.139567 #20962] FATAL -- : [db62fb02-e52e-497f-ae19-4f7eef0db44d]   
F, [2018-10-31T09:31:39.139724 #20962] FATAL -- : [db62fb02-e52e-497f-ae19-4f7eef0db44d] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/favicon.ico"):
I, [2018-10-31T09:31:39.140100 #20962]  INFO -- : [748709e2-db8d-4600-a608-d42f4c58b701] Started GET "/favicon.ico" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-10-31 09:31:39 +0900
F, [2018-10-31T09:31:39.140147 #20962] FATAL -- : [db62fb02-e52e-497f-ae19-4f7eef0db44d]   
F, [2018-10-31T09:31:39.141133 #20962] FATAL -- : [748709e2-db8d-4600-a608-d42f4c58b701]   
F, [2018-10-31T09:31:39.141243 #20962] FATAL -- : [db62fb02-e52e-497f-ae19-4f7eef0db44d] actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:63:in `call'
```

環境は、次のとおりです。

- ubuntu:16.04
- nginx:1.14.0
- puma:3.12.0
- ruby:2.4.2
- rails:12.0.0

何が悪いのか、どうしらた良いのかわかりましたら、ご教示ください。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: rails 12というのはあり得ないと思います。(最新でも開発中なのは6なので) rakeと混同している予感がします。

Answer (score 1):

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/favicon.ico"):

`routes.rb` に GET の  `/favicon.ico` のルートが登録されてないのではないでしょうか。
ルートを設定してもう一度試してみてください。